# С# и sql server. Хочу заполнить таблицы данными из документа word

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-word

Начал делать программу тестер. Дали мне данные тестов(вопросы и варианты ответов) все это хранится в word'овском документе. Так вот, не могли бы вы мне подсказать, что мне надо сделать чтобы можно было через код заполнить таблицу в БД(sqlserver).

Про БД. Предметов будет много, поэтому я решил хранить все вопросы в одной таблице и у каждого вопроса будет атрибут "код предмета". А все ответы хранить в отдельную таблицу с атрибутом "код вопроса".
Если я уже что-то делаю неправильно, поправьте меня пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Если по порядку, то алгоритм решения будет примерно такой:

1. Создаете БД. То, что вы предлагаете, лично у меня вызывает стойкое отторжение после работы с Directum, но для начала, думаю, сойдет.
2. Используете [LINQtoSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb386976(v=vs.110).aspx), создаете .dbml-файл. Получаете объектную модель вашей БД. Как минимум два класса - Questions и Answers.
3. Парсите word'овский документ (либо используя ms-овские возможности - что-то типа Microsoft.Office.Tools, точно не помню, либо сторонними либами - например [Aspose.Word](http://www.aspose.com/.net/word-component.aspx)). Получите что-то такое:

   ```
   //цикл парсинга документа

   Answer answer = new Answer();
   answer.text = данные_из_документа;
   //мб еще что-то
   dbContext.Answers.InsertOnSubmit(answer);

   Question question = new Question();
   question.text = данные_из_документа;
   question.rightAnswerId = --//--;
   //мб еще что-то
   dbContext.Questions.InsertOnSubmit(question);

   dbContext.SubmitChanges();
   ```